# Regular expression works on regex101.com, but not on prod

Tags: regex

https://regex101.com/r/sB9wW6/1

`(?:(?<=\s)|^)@(\S+)` <-- the problem in positive lookbehind

Working like this on `prod`: `(?:\s|^)@(\S+)`, but I need a correct start index (without space).

Here is in JS:

```
var regex = new RegExp(/(?:(?<=\s)|^)@(\S+)/g);
```

> Error parsing regular expression: Invalid regular expression:
>   /(?:(?<=\s)|^)@(\S+)/

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Ok, no lookbehind in JS :(

But anyways, I need a regex to get the proper start and end index of my match. Without leading space.

Comment: There is no lookbehind in Javascript

Comment: Oh, thx! :D I didn't know :D Erm... Any idea how I can reach my goal than? :)

Comment: Next time be careful and select `JavaScript` [like so](https://regex101.com/r/sB9wW6/2)

Comment: It's useful to select the JavaScript option on the left hand side, to verify the syntax is actually valid for JS, not just for PCRE (which is the default)

Comment: In what cases RegEx shouldn't match?

Comment: Always tag your questions with a specific implementation language. Regexes in Python are different from regexes in JavaScript are different from regexes in Java are different from regexes in `grep -E` are different from regexes in emacs are different from bash's built-in regexes...

Comment: ...oh -- I see it *was* tagged that way, but @WiktorStribiżew pulled the tag in making it into a generic reference question. Hmm -- maybe the title and text could use some editing to make it clear that this *is* a general reference question now, without needing to read the answer first.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

**Make sure you always select the right regex engine at regex101.com**. See an issue that occurred due to using a [JS-only compatible regex with `[^]` construct in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29917471/3832970).

JS regex - *at the time of answering this question* - did not support lookbehinds. Now, it becomes more and more adopted after [its introduction in ECMAScript 2018](https://2ality.com/2017/05/regexp-lookbehind-assertions.html). You do not really need it here since you can use capturing groups:

```js
var re = /(?:\s|^)@(\S+)/g; 
var str = 's  @vln1\n@vln2\n';
var res = [];
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  res.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(res);
```

The `(?:\s|^)@(\S+)` matches a whitespace or the start of string with `(?:\s|^)`, then matches `@`, and then matches and *captures* into Group 1  one or more non-whitespace chars with `(\S+)`.

To get the start/end indices, use

```js
var re = /(\s|^)@\S+/g; 
var str = 's  @vln1\n@vln2\n';
var pos = [];
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
  pos.push([m.index+m[1].length, m.index+m[0].length]);
}
console.log(pos);
```

**BONUS**

**My regex works at regex101.com, but not in...**

- **First of all**, have you checked the *Code Generator* link in the *Tools* pane on the left? 
  [image]
- **`All languages - "Literal string" vs. "String literal" alert`** - Make sure you test against the same text used in code, *literal string*, at the regex tester. A common scenario is copy/pasting a [*string literal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal) value directly into the test string field, with all string escape sequences like `\n` (line feed char), `\r` (carriage return), `\t` (tab char). See [Regex_search c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66413191), for example. Mind that they must be replaced with their literal counterparts. So, if you have in Python `text = "Text\n\n abc"`, you must use `Text`, two line breaks, `abc` in the regex tester text field. `Text.*?abc` [will never match it](https://regex101.com/r/qk4rxd/2) although you [might think it "works"](https://regex101.com/r/qk4rxd/1/). Yes, `.` does not always match line break chars, see [How do I match any character across multiple lines in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45981809/3832970)
- **`All languages - Backslash alert`** - Make sure you correctly use a backslash in your *string literal*, in most languages, in *regular string literals*, use double backslash, i.e. `\d` used at regex101.com must written as `\\d`. In *raw string literals*, use a single backslash, same as at regex101. Escaping **word boundary** is very important, since, in many languages ([C#](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/Strings), [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals), [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/characters.html), [JavaScript](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-escapes), [Ruby](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings), etc.), `"\b"` is used to define a BACKSPACE char, i.e. it is a valid *string escape sequence*. PHP does not support `\b` string escape sequence, so `"/\b/"` = `'/\b/'` there.
- **`All languages - Default flags - Global and Multiline`** - Note that by default `m` and `g` flags are enabled at regex101.com. So, if you use `^` and `$`, they will match at the start and end of lines correspondingly. If you need the same behavior in your code check how multiline mode is implemented and either use a specific flag, or - if supported - use an inline `(?m)` embedded (inline) modifier. The `g` flag enables multiple occurrence matching, it is often implemented using specific functions/methods. Check your language reference to find the appropriate one.
- [line-breaks](/questions/tagged/line-breaks) - **Line endings** at regex101.com are LF only, you can't test strings with CRLF endings, see [regex101.com VS myserver - different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39511868). Solutions can be different for each regex library: either use `\R` (PCRE, Java, Ruby) or some kind of `\v` (Boost, PCRE),  `\r?\n`, `(?:\r\n?|\n)`/`(?>\r\n?|\n)` (good for .NET) or `[\r\n]+` in other libraries (see answers for [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49106318/regex-c-sharp-doesnt-match-when-regex101-does/49106391#49106391), [PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39512242/3832970)). 
   Another issue related to the fact that you test your regex against a multiline string (not a list of standalone strings/lines) is that your patterns may consume the end of line, `\n`, char with negated character classes, see [an issue like that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42096896/3832970). `\D` matched the end of line char, and in order to avoid it, `[^\d\n]` could be used, or other alternatives.
- [php](/questions/tagged/php)
   - You are dealing with Unicode strings, or want shorthand character classes to match Unicode characters, too (e.g. `\w+` to match `Стрибижев` or `Stribiżew`, or `\s+` to match hard spaces), then you need to use [`u` modifier](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), see  [preg_match() returns 0 although regex testers work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37900273/3832970) 
   - To match all occurrences, use [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), not `preg_match` with `/...pattern.../g`, see [PHP preg_match to find multiple occurrences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2029976) and ["Unknown modifier 'g' in..." when using preg_match in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578671)
  - Your regex with inline backreference like `\1` refuses to work? Are you using a double quoted string literal? Use a single-quoted one, see [Backreference does not work in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383383)
- [php](/questions/tagged/php)[laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel)
   - Mind you need the regex delimiters around the pattern, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22430529
- [python](/questions/tagged/python)
   - Note that `re.search`, `re.match`, `re.fullmatch`, `re.findall` and `re.finditer` accept the regex as the *first* argument, and the input *string* as the *second* argument. Not `re.findall("test 200 300", r"\d+")`, but `re.findall(r"\d+", "test 200 300")`. If you test at regex101.com, please check the "Code Generator" page.
   - You used `re.match` that only searches for a match at the start of the string, use `re.search`: [Regex works fine on Pythex, but not in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31975921/regex-works-fine-on-pythex-but-not-in-python) 
   - If the regex contains capturing group(s), `re.findall` returns a list of captures/capture tuples. Either use non-capturing groups, or `re.finditer`, or remove redundant capturing groups, see [re.findall behaves weird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915018)
   - If you used `^` in the pattern to denote start of a line, not start of the whole string, or used `$` to denote the end of a line and not a string, pass `re.M` or `re.MULTILINE` flag to `re` method, see [Using ^ to match beginning of line in Python regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31400362/using-to-match-beginning-of-line-in-python-regex/31400426#31400426)
   
   - If you try to match some text across multiple lines, and use `re.DOTALL` or `re.S`, or `[\s\S]*` / `[\s\S]*?`, and still nothing works, check if you read the file line by line, say, with `for line in file:`. You must pass the whole file contents as the input to the regex method, see [Getting Everything Between Two Characters Across New Lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61389990). 
   - Having trouble adding flags to regex and trying something like `pattern = r"/abc/gi"`? See [How to add modifers to regex in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31916471/3832970)
- [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), [.net](/questions/tagged/.net)
   - .NET regex does not support *possessive quantifiers* like `++`, `*+`, `??`, `{1,10}?`, see [.NET regex matching digits between optional text with possessive quantifer is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42775136) 
   - When you match against a multiline string and use `RegexOptions.Multiline` option (or inline `(?m)` modifier) with an `$` anchor in the pattern to match *entire lines*, and get no match in code, you need to add `\r?` before `$`, see [.Net regex matching $ with the end of the string and not of line, even with multiline enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058265) 
   - To get **multiple matches**, use `Regex.Matches`, not `Regex.Match`, see [RegEx Match multiple times in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4892452) 
   - Similar case as above: splitting a string into paragraphs, by a double line break sequence - [C# / Regex Pattern works in online testing, but not at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55434026) 
   - You should remove regex delimiters, i.e. `@"/\d+/"` must actually look like `@"\d+"`, see [Simple and tested online regex containing regex delimiters does not work in C# code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31560080/) 
   - If you unnecessarily used `Regex.Escape` to escape all characters in a regular expression (like `Regex.Escape(@"\d+\.\d+")`) you need to remove `Regex.Escape`, see [Regular Expression working in regex tester, but not in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24687028)
- [dart](/questions/tagged/dart)[flutter](/questions/tagged/flutter)
   - Use raw string literal, `RegExp(r"\d")`, or double backslashes (`RegExp("\\d")`) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59085824
- [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)
   - Double escape backslashes in a `RegExp("\\d")`: [Why do regex constructors need to be double escaped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17863066)

   - (Negative) lookbehinds unsupported by most browsers: [Regex works on browser but not in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48263642/regex-works-on-browser-but-not-in-node-js) 
  - Strings are immutable, assign the `.replace` result to a var - [The .replace() method does change the string in place](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13475581) 
  - Retrieve *all* matches with `str.match(/pat/g)` - [Regex101 and Js regex search showing different results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43457366) or, with `RegExp#exec`, [RegEx to extract all matches from string using RegExp.exec](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323417)
  - Replace *all* pattern matches in string: [Why does javascript replace only first instance when using replace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967119)
- [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)[angular](/questions/tagged/angular)
   - Double the backslashes if you define a regex with a string literal, or just use a regex literal notation, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56097782
- [java](/questions/tagged/java)
   - Word boundary not working? Make sure you use double backslashes, `"\\b"`, see [Regex \b word boundary not works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938990)
   - Getting `invalid escape sequence` exception? Same thing, double backslashes - [Java doesn't work with regex \s, says: invalid escape sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733255)
   - `No match found` is bugging you? Run `Matcher.find()` / `Matcher.matches()` -  [Why does my regex work on RegexPlanet and regex101 but not in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433104)
   - `.matches()` requires a full string match, use `.find()`: [Java Regex pattern that matches in any online tester but doesn't in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30912978) 
  - Access groups using `matcher.group(x)`: [Regex not working in Java while working otherwise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44926979)
   - Inside a character class, both `[` and `]` must be escaped - [Using square brackets inside character class in Java regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41568858) 
  - You should not run `matcher.matches()` and `matcher.find()` consecutively, use only `if (matcher.matches()) {...}` to check if the pattern matches the whole string and then act accordingly, or use `if (matcher.find())` to check if there is a single match or `while (matcher.find())` to find multiple matches (or [`Matcher#results()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#results--)). See [Why does my regex work on RegexPlanet and regex101 but not in my code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32433104)
- [scala](/questions/tagged/scala)
   - Your regex attempts to match several lines, but you read the file line by line (e.g. use `for (line <- fSource.getLines)`)? Read it into a single variable (see [matching new line in Scala regex, when reading from file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69071962/3832970))
- [kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin)
   - You have `Regex("/^\\d+$/")`? Remove the outer slashes, they are [regex delimiter chars](https://riptutorial.com/regex/example/15849/-delimiters-) that are not part of a pattern. See [Find one or more word in string using Regex in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68081933)
   - You expect a partial string match, but `.matchEntire` requires a full string match? Use `.find`, see [Regex doesn't match in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43097461)
- [mongodb](/questions/tagged/mongodb)
   - Do not enclose `/.../` with single/double quotation marks, see [mongodb regex doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48246544)
- [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b)
   - `regex_match` requires a full string match, use `regex_search` to find a partial match - [Regex not working as expected with C++ regex_match](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31110541/3832970)
   - `regex_search` finds the first match only. Use `sregex_token_iterator` or `sregex_iterator` to get all matches: see [What does std::match_results::size return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32765512/what-does-stdmatch-resultssize-return/32765645#32765645)
   - When you read a user-defined string using `std::string input; std::cin >> input;`, note that `cin` will only get to the first whitespace, to read the whole line properly, use `std::getline(std::cin, input);` - [C++ Regex to match '+' quantifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262889) 
   - `"\d"` does not work, you need to use `"\\d"` or `R"(\d)"` (*a raw string literal*) - [This regex doesn't work in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31098881)
   - Make sure the regex is tested against a literal text, not a string literal, see [Regex_search c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66413191)
- [go](/questions/tagged/go)
   - Double backslashes or use a raw string literal: [Regular expression doesn't work in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14183704) 
   - Go regex does not support lookarounds, select the right option (`Go`) at regex101.com before testing! [Regex expression negated set not working golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47211017)
- [groovy](/questions/tagged/groovy)
   - Return all matches: [Regex that works on regex101 does not work in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42811719)
- [r](/questions/tagged/r)
   - Double escape backslashes in the string literal: ["'\w' is an unrecognized escape" in grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27528581/w-is-an-unrecognized-escape-in-grep?noredirect=1)
   - Use `perl=TRUE` to PCRE engine (`(g)sub`/`(g)regexpr`): [Why is this regex using lookbehinds invalid in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13420391)
- [oracle](/questions/tagged/oracle)
   - Greediness of all quantifiers is set by the first quantifier in the regex, see [Regex101 vs Oracle Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45302698) (then, you need to make all the quantifiers as greedy as the first one)]
   - `\b` does not work? Oracle regex does not support word boundaries at all, use workarounds as shown in [Regex matching works on regex tester but not in oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70072721/3832970)
- [firebase](/questions/tagged/firebase)
   - Double escape backslashes, make sure `^` only appears at the start of the pattern and `$` is located only at the end (if any), and note you cannot use more than 9 inline backreferences: [Firebase Rules Regex Birthday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50571573)
- [firebase](/questions/tagged/firebase)[google-cloud-firestore](/questions/tagged/google-cloud-firestore)
   - In Firestore security rules, the regular expression needs to be passed as a string, which also means it shouldn't be wrapped in `/` symbols, i.e. use `allow create: if docId.matches("^\\d+$")`.... See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63243300
- [google-data-studio](/questions/tagged/google-data-studio)
   - `/pattern/g` in `REGEXP_REPLACE` must contain no `/` regex delimiters and flags (like `g`) - see [How to use Regex to replace square brackets from date field in Google Data Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61973919)
- [google-sheets](/questions/tagged/google-sheets)
   - If you think `REGEXEXTRACT` does not return full matches, truncates the results, you should check if you have redundant capturing groups in your regex and remove them, or convert the capturing groups to non-capturing by add `?:` after the opening `(`, see [Extract url domain root in Google Sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64098613)
- [sed](/questions/tagged/sed)
   - [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905)
- [word-boundary](/questions/tagged/word-boundary)[pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre)[php](/questions/tagged/php)
   - `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` do not work in the regex tester, although they are valid constructs in PCRE, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48670105
- [snowflake-cloud-data-platform](/questions/tagged/snowflake-cloud-data-platform) [snowflake-sql](/questions/tagged/snowflake-sql) - If you are writing a stored procedure, and `\\d` does not work, you need to double them again and use `\\\\d`, see [REGEX conversion of VARCHAR value to DATE in Snowflake stored procedure using RLIKE not consistent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69907458/3832970).

Comment: My main goal is to get start and end indexes.

Comment: The indexes of what? The pos after `@`?

Comment: Index of '@' and end of word. Now in case of start of the string I get 0, and in case of middle text - index - 1 (coz of matched space)

Comment: @Kindzoku let's backtrack - _why_ do you need the indeces? Because I am not sure a regex would help, even if it worked.

Comment: Well, I added another snippet to return the list of start and end positions of `@\S+`-matching values. Really, no idea why you need them.

Comment: Actualy, lookehind checking, without taking. So it is working. Why, is really not important. There is a lot of ways I can handle this. I just wanted to do it in an elegant way. I have `(?:\s|^)@(\S+)` at the start. I used lookbehind to get rid of space.

Comment: So I guess it's not doable by regex then.

Comment: Oh! That's it. Well, actually I still need the match, so `/(\s|^)@(\S+)/g`, but `m.index+m[1].length` - pretty smart! In my current solution I'm checking for a `' '` on zero index and do +1 in this case. But your solution is a lot better. Thx :) I think it'll be better to reduce the answer to second part.

Comment: Double Backslash  for metacharacters in Javascript string literals!!!!!   For The Win!!!!(eg, new RegExp( ) needs RegExp('\\s)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56097782 

This must be the most helpful answer in the history of the platform