# Regular expression exclude one word

Tags: regex

I want to write a regular expression that find all strings looks "animals.* " On the '*' place can be any symbols, but not 'elephant'.

Result should be:

> Input: animals.fox => Result: animals.fox
>
> Input: animals.kitten => Result: animals.kitten

But

> Input: animals.elephant => Result: None

I write a regular expression, but it not work properly. How to fix it?

```
animals\.(?!elephant)
```

Comment: Do you mean you need to match the words to the end? Try [`animals\.(?!elephant)\w+`](https://regex101.com/r/pT3cL6/1)

Comment: @Евгений, Did my answer help?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the only problem is with matching the word after `.`. The lookahead you used is a *zero-width assertion* that does not put the matched chars into the output, it just checks if the text to the right of the current location does not match its pattern. If it matches, the match is failed. Else, it just returns *true*. So, you need to *consume* the word after the `.`.

Add `[a-zA-Z]+` or `\w+` at the end of your pattern (depending on what you need to match, just letters or letter/digits/underscore):

```
animals\.(?!elephant\b)\w+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pT3cL6/23)

**Please mind** that in many languages when you define the regex pattern using string literals, you need to double escape backslashes. See [Regular expression works on regex101.com, but not on prod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636124/regular-expression-works-on-regex101-com-but-not-on-prod)