# .Net regex matching $ with the end of the string and not of line, even with multiline enabled

Tags: c#, regex, uwp, markdown, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to highlight markdown code, but am running into this weird behavior of the .NET regex multiline option.

The following expression: `^(#+).+$` works fine on any online regex testing tool:

[image]

But it refuses to work with .net:

[image]

It doesn't seem to take into account the $ tag, and just highlights everything until the end of the string, no matter what. This is my C#

```
RegExpression = new Regex(@"^(#+).+$", RegexOptions.Multiline)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: A dot cannot match a LF without a DOTALL modifier. Can you please share a dotnetfidle?

Comment: You have a CR ending. Use `@"^(#+).+?\r?$"`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is clear your text contains a linebreak other than LF. In .NET regex, a dot matches any char but LF (a newline char, `\n`).

See [*Multiline Mode* MSDN regex reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options#multiline-mode)

> By default, `$` matches only the end of the input string. If you specify the [RegexOptions.Multiline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions#System_Text_RegularExpressions_RegexOptions_Multiline) option, it matches either the newline character (`\n`) or the end of the input string. It does not, however, match the carriage return/line feed character combination. To successfully match them, use the subexpression `\r?$` instead of just `$`.

So, use

```
@"^(#+).+?\r?$"
```

The `.+?\r?$` will match lazily any one or more chars other than LF up to the first CR (that is optional) right before a newline.

Or just use a negated character class:

```
@"^(#+)[^\r\n]+"
```

The  `[^\r\n]+` will match one or more chars other than CR/LF.

Comment: Unfortunately when I use `Regex.Replacec` it replaces and `\r ` character (( Can I fix it?

Comment: @Deni35 It seems you have a new question, please ask

Comment: One could match end of line with this pattern: `(?=\r?$)`

Answer (score 0):

What you have is good. The only thing you're missing is that `.` doesn't match newline characters, even with the multiline option. You can get around this in two different ways.

The easiest is to use the [RegexOptions.Singleline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx#Singleline) flag which cause newlines to be treated as characters. That way, `^` still matches the start of the string, `$` matches the end of the string and `.` matches everything ***including*** newlines.

The other way to fix this (although I wouldn't recomend it for your use case) is to modify your regex to explicitly allow newlines. To do this you can just replace any `.` with `(?:.|\n)` which means either anycharacter or a newline. For your example, you would end up with `^(#+)(?:.|\n)+$`. If you want to ensure that there's a non-linebreak character first, add an extra dot: `^(#+).(?:.|\n)+$`

Comment: I think you've misunderstood my question. I don't want to match new lines. The second image is what I've got, and the first image is what I SHOULD get. The input string "this is a \n #header \n but this isn't" should only match "#header". Currently, it's matching "#header but this isn't"

Comment: Please never suggest `(?:.|\n)+` pattern. It is very inefficient and can cause system freeze because of the number of backtracking (or expansion in case of lazy quantifier) steps it has to perform. Always use `.` with the `(?s)` inline modifier or `RegexOptions.Singleline` in .NET. You do not need to every use the `[\s\S]` like workarounds as you may use modifier groups in .NET regex. e.g.: `^.*\r?\n(?s:.*)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for suggesting `(?s:.*)` – that certainly looks useful. I'm a little confused as to why `(?:.|\n)` causes performance issues, could you elaborate or link to a resource that explains why?

Comment: @Vopel I hope I explained everything in [this YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SEobSs-ZCSE).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's helpful, thanks. How does `(?s:.*)` compare to `([s\S]*)` though? The latter seems like it would be good if you don't want the entire expression to have the Singleline flag enabled.

Comment: @Vopel `.` can match line breaks if you apply the `s` flag/modifier on it. In .NET regex, it is supported. In JavaScript, it is not, so in JavaScript, you usually resort to `[\s\S]`, although ECMAScript regex supports a `[^]` construct that matches any character. `[^]` is not used much since it is not compliant with any other engine.