# Trivial multiline regex fails in .NET but succeeds in ECMAScript - why?

Tags: javascript, .net, regex

I'm writing a quick utility program in C# to modify all of my Visual Studio C# item templates to add extra `using ;` statements. I've written a simple regular-expression to (hackishly) extract the set of current namespaces imports in each file so I can add my desired new imports without duplication.

I'm using [Regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) to test my regular-expressions before inserting them into my C# program, but when I tested them in my C# program they didn't work. This confuses me because the regex itself is trivial, it uses regex conventions common to both .NET and ECMAScript regular-expressions *and* it also fails even with the `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` compatibility option.

```
const String input = @"using System;
using System.Foo;

using Foo.Bar;

namespace Foo
{
    using Baz;

    class Qux
    {

    }
}";

Regex regex = new Regex( @"^using ([\w\.]+)\;$", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.ECMAScript );

Match match = regex.Match( input );

Assert.IsTrue( match.Success ); // `match.Success` is false when I run this code
```

I don't understand why, because the behaviour of `\w`, `^`, `$` and the multiline options is ostensibly the same in both platforms.

Here is a screenshot showing it succeeding in Regex101.com:

[image]

Here is a screenshot showing it failing in .NET:

[image]

Comment: If you use CRLF linebreaks, the dollar matches right between them, so add `\r` right in front.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.Net regex matching $ with the end of the string and not of line, even with multiline enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058265/net-regex-matching-with-the-end-of-the-string-and-not-of-line-even-with-mult)

Comment: @SebastianProske Argh, thank you. Methinks the maintainers of .NET should add a `RegexOptions.MatchCRLFNewLine`! This design issue is not very well documented in the .NET reference guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that '$' in multiline mode matches a '`\n`', not '`\r\n`', which is the default linebreak on Windows. The solution is simply to add '`\r?`' in front of the '`$`' linebreak, like this:

```
^using ([\w\.]+);\r?$
```

Now it will match both '`\n`' and '`\r\n`'.

**Edit**:

When you enter a multiline text on RegEx101, they use '\n' as linebreaks, that's why it Works on their site.