# Using square brackets inside character class in Java regex

Tags: java, regex

Below is the regex I have written to replace the special chars `&!)(}{][^"~*?:;\+-` from a string, but somehow it is not able to replace `[` & `]` from it as it acts as beginning and closing of regex. How can I do that?

```
System.out.println(" &!)(}{][^\"~*?:;\\+-".replaceAll("[| |&|!|)|(|}|{|^|\"|~|*|?|:|;|\\\\|+|-]", "_"));
}
```

The output for now : `_______][__________`

Comment: `System.out.println(" &!)(}{][^\"~*?:;\\+-".replaceAll("[\\[\\] &!)(}{^\"~*?:;\\\\+-]", "_"));
`Here is your code improved a bit, no need for all the `|`'s. The way to go is to escape the brackets. you do that by puting a `\` before it, but in the case of java you need to escape the `\` itself therefore you put two `\`'s before the bracket. :)

Comment: Actually, `|` in the pattern was a bug. Removing it from the character class is not just an improvement, it is a fix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to escape the `[` and `]` inside a character class in a Java regex.

Also, you do not need to put `|` as alternation symbol in the character class as it is treated as a literal `|`.

```
System.out.println(" &!)(}{][^\"~*?:;\\+-".replaceAll("[\\]\\[ &!)(}{^\"~*?:;\\\\+-]", "_"));
// => ___________________
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/Op70WY)

---

†: <sub>Note that in PCRE/Python/.NET, POSIX, you do not have to escape square brackets in the character class if you put them at the right places: `[]ab[]`. In JavaScript, you always have to escape ]: `/[^\]abc[]/`. In Java and ICU regexps, you must always escape both `[` and `]` inside the character class. – Wiktor Stribiżew Jan 10 '17 at 12:39</sub>