# .NET regex matching digits between optional text with possessive quantifer is not working

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have this regex:

```
Regex myRegex = new Regex(@"^[a-zA-Z .:_-]+([0-9]+)[a-zA-Z .:_-]*+$");
```

and I would like to match a digit code this way:

- "Order No. 0123456 lorem ipsum" - MATCH 0123456 in Group 1
- "No. 0123456" - MATCH 0123456 in Group 1
- "Order 0123456" - MATCH 0123456 in Group 1
- "013456 lorem ipsum" - NO MATCH

This works here: https://regex101.com/
but not in .NET with C# as I have this exception:

```
"System.ArgumentException: parsing "^[a-zA-Z .:_-]+([0-9]+)[a-zA-Z .:_-]*+$" - Nested quantifier +.
   at System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexParser.ScanRegex()
   at System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexParser.Parse(String re, RegexOptions op)
   at System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex..ctor(String pattern, RegexOptions options, TimeSpan matchTimeout, Boolean useCache)
   at System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex..ctor(String pattern)
   at Rextester.Program.AnalyzeFreetext(String freeText)
   at Rextester.Program.Main(String[] args)"
```

Is there an alternative an maybe more elegant way to capture the digits between text (mandatory before digits, optional after).

Thank you.

Comment: `*+` is a possessive quantifier, and .NET regex does not support them. Replace with `*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*+` is a possessive quantifier, and .NET regex does not support them. Replace `*+` with `*` as you did not mean to use a possessive quantifier here.

Here is the mapping:

```
?+     => ?
*+     => *
++     => +
{2}+   => {2}
{2,}+  => {2,}
{2,9}+ => {2,9}
```

Use

```
^[a-zA-Z .:_-]+([0-9]+)[a-zA-Z .:_-]*$
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5ba-zA-Z+.%3a_-%5d%2b%28%5b0-9%5d%2b%29%5ba-zA-Z+.%3a_-%5d*%5cr%3f%24&i=Order+No.+0123456+lorem+ipsum%0d%0aNo.+0123456%0d%0aOrder+0123456%0d%0a013456+lorem+ipsum&o=m).

[image]

An alternative regex can be used here, that will match `Order` or `No.`, then 0+ whitespaces and then will capture 1+ digits:

```
(?:Order|No\.)\s*([0-9]+)
```

See [another regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3AOrder%7CNo%5C.%29%5Cs*%28%5B0-9%5D%2B%29&i=Order%20No.%200123456%20lorem%20ipsum%0D%0ANo.%200123456%0D%0AOrder%200123456%0D%0A013456%20lorem%20ipsum&o=m)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following Regex which enforces anything else prior the digits then captures the digits:

```
\D+(\d+)
```

See the details below.

`\D` means anything else but digits
`+` at least 1 time
`\d` digits only
`+` at least 1 time

Feel free to ask questions in the comments.