# Regex that works on regex101 does not work in Groovy

Tags: regex, groovy

I have the following regex

```
def formula = math:min(math:round($$value1$$ * $$value2$$) ) 
def m = formula =~ /\$\$\w+\$\$/
println m.group(1)
```

Above should ideally print `$$value1$$`.

Now this regex for the following string works fine on regex101.com but same does not work on Groovy. Ideally it should find two groups $$value1$$ and $$value2$$ using Matcher API, but it does not.

Is there anything wrong in this regex?

Comment: Hi @collinD please check my latest edit.

Comment: Show your Groovy or Java code. Note that a regex that works at regex101 does not have to work in Java, as regex101 does not support Java regex syntax.

Comment: That's Groovy, not Java

Comment: Hi @CollinD please check now everything should make sense.

Comment: Does it mean you need to get `[value1, value2]`, not `[$$value1$$, $$value2$$]`?

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew I need actual values [$$value1$$, $$value2$$] which I will eventually replace with other values findAll seems to be working.

Comment: Then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `formula` is:

```
def formula = 'math:min(math:round($$value1$$ * $$value2$$) )'
```

I think you just want:

```
List result = formula.findAll(/\$\$\w+\$\$/)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried your regex in java and it works for me if i remove the `/` at the beginning and the end of the regex.

```
public class RegexTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String regex = "\\$\\$\\w+\\$\\$";
    String test = "math:min(math:round($$value1$$ * $$value2$$) ) ";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(test);
    while (matcher.find()){
      System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }    
  }
}
```

it returns

```
$$value1$$
$$value2$$
```