# Regex doesn't match in Kotlin

Tags: regex, kotlin

I can't understand why this simple regex doesn't match anything. It always fails and throws exception:

```
    val match = Regex("""\d+""").matchEntire("A123B")?: throw Exception("Regex fail")
```

Comment: You seem to want to match a whole string with `\d+`, but your `A123B` does not only consist of digits.

Comment: Just a note: if you need to match these strings in full and they consist of alphanumeric characters, you may use the `\p{Alnum}+` pattern. Or if only uppercase letters and digits are allowed, use `[A-Z0-9]+`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to match an entire input with [`matchEntire`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/match-entire.html) and a `\d+` pattern:

> `fun matchEntire(input: CharSequence): MatchResult? (source)`
>   Attempts to match the entire input CharSequence against the pattern.
>   
>   Return An instance of MatchResult if the entire input matches or null otherwise.

However, `A123B` does not only consist of digits. If you need to find a partial match, use [`find`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/-regex/find.html).