# Regex101 and Js regex search showing different results

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string comprised of my name `christiancattano` and a regex search pattern defined as such

```
/(cattano|cattan|attano|chris|catta|attan|ttano|chri|hris|catt|atta|ttan|tano|chr|hri|ris|cat|att|tta|tan|ano)+/ig
```

In regex101 if I enter my search pattern in the top bar, and enter verbatim, `christiancattano` into the test string box it will hightlight `chris`and `cattano`. This is the behaviour I am expecting.

In my javascript code if I run the following lines

```
var regExPattern: string = '(cattano|cattan|attano|chris|catta|attan|ttano|chri|hris|catt|atta|ttan|tano|chr|hri|ris|cat|att|tta|tan|ano)+';

var regExObj: RegExp = new RegExp(regExPattern, 'g');

var match: string[] = regExObj.exec('christiancattano');

console.log(`match: ${match}`);
```

I receive this output

```
match: chris,chris
```

Why is it that regex101 shows my matches being what I expect, `chris` and `cattano`, but my Javascript code is producing a different result?

Comment: Use `match`: `'christiancattano'.match(regExObj)`

Comment: In Javascript, when you execute a RegExp with the `g` modifier, it just returns one match at a time. You have to call it in a loop to get all the matches. Remove the modifier.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew my man! You did it again! Thank you so much! I've just read into the differences between string.match(), and regex.exec(), and I see where I went wrong in attempting to get a string[] of my matches. Thank you again so much for your help today!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RegExp#exec()` only returns a single match object, even if you use a regex with the `g` modifier.

You may use `String#match` with a regex with the `g` modifier to get all match values:

```
var match: string[] = 'christiancattano'.match(regExObj)
```