# Regex not working in Java while working otherwise

Tags: java, regex, intellij-idea

I made a regular expression: https://regex101.com/r/ToCwrE/2/

All it should do, is get out the function's parameters. I am trying with capture groups to achieve this.

`[\s]*javascript:[\s]*m\((-?\d+)[\s]*,[\s]*(-?\d+)[\s]*,[\s]{0,}encodeURIComponent\(\'([^\']+)*\'\)[\s]*,[\s]*(-?\d+)\)[\s]*`

Tried it on:

```
javascript:m(53009,2,encodeURIComponent('7711T'), 22)
javascript:m(52992,2,encodeURIComponent('3013'), 2)
javascript:m(10440,2,encodeURIComponent('F Series'), 11)
javascript:m(53022,2,encodeURIComponent('C 12045'), 85)
javascript:m(53045,2,encodeURIComponent('Prox 8441'), 16)
javascript:m(26016,2,encodeURIComponent('Vard   asd .ious'), 22)
```

Using the site regex101 and a few similar ones, it correctly returns the matched groups. However when I am trying to use it in Java, it simply won't match the capture groups and only returns the whole text.

If I copy paste it with IDEA, It automatically gets escaped (replaces \ to \):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\s]*javascript:[\\s]*m\\((-?\\d+)[\\s]*,[\\s]*(-?\\d+)[\\s]*,[\\s]{0,}encodeURIComponent\\(\\'([^\\']+)*\\'\\)[\\s]*,[\\s]*(-?\\d+)\\)[\\s]*");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher("javascript:m(53022,2,encodeURIComponent('Cr 12045'), 85)");
List<String> groups = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {
    groups.add(m.group());
}
groups;
```

[image]

What am I missing? How should the regex be converted to get it working in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get content of each group you can use `Matcher#group(number)` or `Matcher#group(name)`. In your case to get content of first group use `m.group(1)` and you will get `53022`.

Problem with `m.group()` is that it is same as `m.group(0)` so it returns content of group 0, which holds match for whole pattern.

To iterate over all groups use simple for loop. To dynamically get amounts of groups in pattern use `Matcher#groupCount`.

So to put results from all groups you can use

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\s]*javascript:[\\s]*m\\((-?\\d+)[\\s]*,[\\s]*(-?\\d+)[\\s]*,[\\s]{0,}encodeURIComponent\\(\\'([^\\']+)*\\'\\)[\\s]*,[\\s]*(-?\\d+)\\)[\\s]*");
Matcher m = p.matcher("javascript:m(53022,2,encodeURIComponent('Cr 12045'), 85)");
List<String> groups = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {
    for (int i=1; i<=m.groupCount(); i++){
        groups.add(m.group(i));
    }
}

System.out.println(groups); //[53022, 2, Cr 12045, 85]
```

BTW

- `\s` is already character class so it doesn't need to be nested in `[..]`, so instead of `[\\s]*` you can write `\\s*`.
- `{0,}` is same as `*` so I don't see any reason to mix those two, use `*` everywhere
- `'` is not regex metacharacter so it doesn't need escaping

Comment: Thanks for the regex tips, even though I know them and I just played around too much with the regex, because I thought it was the cause :(

Answer (score 2):

The regex is matching correctly, it's just how you reference each group using m.group(). The following should help:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class JavaTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[\\s]*javascript:[\\s]*m\\((-?\\d+)[\\s]*,[\\s]*(-?\\d+)[\\s]*,[\\s]{0,}encodeURIComponent\\(\\'([^\\']+)*\\'\\)[\\s]*,[\\s]*(-?\\d+)\\)[\\s]*");
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher("javascript:m(53009,2,encodeURIComponent('7711T'), 22)");
        if (m.find()) {
            for (int i=1 ; i <= m.groupCount() ; i++) {
                System.out.println(m.group(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Provides the output:

```
53009
2
7711T
22
```