# Regex101 vs Oracle Regex

Tags: regex, oracle

My regex:

```
^\+?(-?)0*([[:digit:]]+,[[:digit:]]+?)0*$
```

It is removing leading + and leading and tailing 0s in decimal number.

I have tested it in [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/erFPtk/2)

For input: `+000099,8420000` and substitution `\1\2` it returns `99,842`

I want the same result in Oracle database 11g:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('+000099,8420000','^\+?(-?)0*([[:digit:]]+,[[:digit:]]+?)0*$','\1\2') from dual;
```

But it returns `99,8420000` (tailing 0s are still present...)

What I'm missing?

**EDIT**

It works like greedy quantifier `*` at the end of regex, not lazy `*?` but I definitely set lazy one.

Comment: How do you know which 0 is part of the number? how you represent 9,000?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew source?

Comment: @user7294900 it is easy. There is lazy quantifier who will catch at least one  zero from the tailing 0s

Comment: I am checking the docs, but I suspect the regex engine is based on Henry Spencer's regex library. And that means the reason is much deeper since it supports lazy quantifiers. The solution is easy.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I would appreciate if you would post the solution as answer

Comment: what's your oracle version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is well-known for all those who worked with Henry Spencer's regex library implementations: **lazy quantifiers should not be mixed up with greedy quantifiers in one and the same branch** since that leads to undefined behavior. The TRE regex engine used in R shows the same behavior. While you may mix the lazy and greedy quantifiers to some extent, you must always make sure you get a consistent result.

The solution is to only use lazy quantifiers inside the capturing group:

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE('+000099,8420000', '^\+?(-?)0*([0-9]+?,[0-9]+?)0*$','\1\2') as Result from dual
```

See the [online demo](http://rextester.com/TGVM75852)

The `[0-9]+?,[0-9]+?` part matches 1 or more digits but as few times as possible followed with a comma and then 1 or more digits, as few as possible.

Some more tests (`select REGEXP_REPLACE('+00009,010020','[0-9]+,[0-9]+?([1-9])','\1') from dual` yields `+20`) prove that **the first quantifier in a *group* sets the quantifier greediness type**. In the case above, Group 0 quantifier greediness is set to *greedy* by the first `?` quantifier, and Group 1 (i.e. `([0-9]+?,[0-9]+?)`) greediness type is set with the first `+?` (which is lazy).

[image]

Comment: Almost. It is not working when after `,` we have only 0s like: `+000099,0000000`

Comment: @ilovkatie I think yours doesn't either. Your dwelled upon different issues in the question. What is the expected result for `+000099,0000000`? What are other test cases?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/erFPtk/3 it is working. Output should be `99,0`. But as your answer points, it will not work for oracle.

Comment: Ok, the lazy quantifiers can be used inside Group 1, and that will work - `'^\+?(-?)0*([0-9]+?,[0-9]+?)0*$'` - http://rextester.com/SQZP50172, see the question update. I mentioned that the behavior is inconsistent, but not making it impossible to mix up the quantifier types.

Comment: Check my updated clarification. I think it should all be clear now.