# Regex works on browser but not in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a regex: `/(?<!\<)\<[a-zA-Z0-9. _]+\>/g`. Works fine in browser console if I do `"(<<a1>> * <b1> * <c1> * <d1>) * <<e1>>".match(/(?<!\<)\<[a-zA-Z0-9. _]+\>/g)`.

Same line of code throws `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /(?<!<)<([a-zA-Z0-9. _]+)>/: Invalid group` when executed in Node.js.

I want to match all variables in my string enclosed in `<` and `>` ignore them if enclosed by `<<` and `>>`.

Comment: which browser??

Comment: Copy/pasting that line of code in the Safari's Console throws the error *SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: unrecognized character after (?* when I test it.

Comment: same here in chrome , its invalid regex

Comment: "SyntaxError: invalid regexp group" in Firefox (but worked in chrome console for me)

Comment: Interesting... It works for me in Chrome also and the latest Node.js (9.4.0), but not in https://ideone.com/GkoCSN

Comment: There are no negative lookbehinds in `JavaScript`, thus `(?<!)` is invalid (unless `node.js` uses some other regular expression engine).

Comment: Okay, [Latest versions of V8 have support for Lookbehind assertions](https://v8project.blogspot.in/2017/07/upcoming-regexp-features.html). That is why it is working in the latest Node.js and Chrome (they both use latest V8 engine).

Comment: @Liam In Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex (might need slight changes, depending if you want to detect beginning/end of lines, or these kind of subtilities). I added a caturing group around the value inside the `<>` because this regex will also match the char before the `<` and after the `>`.

if your `<>` can be placed at beginning/end of string:

```
/(?:[^<]|^)\<([a-zA-Z0-9. _]+)\>(?:[^<]|$)/g
```

If you don't need:

```
/(?:[^<])\<([a-zA-Z0-9. _]+)\>(?:[^<])/g
```

NOTE: Not sure of this, but might be quicker than a negative lookbehind.

EDIT: from your comments, i'm not sure you know capturing groups. It allows you to extract parts of your regex, not obligatory the whole matched expression.

To use them in Javascript see this example (note that you have to remove the `/` at the start and end of the regex and escape the `\` too for regex objects):

```js
var myRegex = new RegExp('(?:[^<]|^)\\<([a-zA-Z0-9. _]+)\\>(?:[^<]|$)', 'g'), testStr = '(<<a1>> * <b1> * <c1> * <d1>) * <<e1>>', match, elem = document.getElementById('result');

while (match = myRegex.exec(testStr)) {
  elem.innerHTML = elem.innerHTML + match[1] + '<br>';
}
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: It gave me `[ ' <b1> ', ' <c1> ', ' <d1>)' ]` this array. It took unwanted chars. I want it to return `[ '<b1>', '<c1>', '<d1>' ]`

Comment: I added a commentary about that, that's why I added a capturing group to the regex. It matches the chars before and after, but in the capturing groups you will have the values that are inside the `<>`. If you really want the `<>` in the capturing groups, you can change to: `/(?:[^<]|^)(\<[a-zA-Z0-9. _]+\>)(?:[^<]|$)/g`

Comment: it works for me: https://regex101.com/r/2fppPC/2 what didn't work exactly?

Comment: It is taking single surrounding characters along.

Comment: @A.B. i edited my answer, tell me if you still have problems

Comment: Okay. I'll loop through and add <> manually to each item I get. Thanks by the way.

Comment: @A.B. not obliged to add the `<>` manually, you can use the modified regex in my second comment if you want to keep them

Answer (score 3):

As an answer as well (more space):
Unless `node.js` uses it's own regex engine and not the `JavaScript` one, lookbehinds are not supported in `JS`, thus `(?<!)` cannot work. To somewhat mimic this feature from other programming languages, have a look at [**Flagrant Badassery**](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript) or use additional packages like [**`node-re2`**](https://github.com/uhop/node-re2) or [**`node-perl-regex`**](https://github.com/Aludirk/node-perl-regex).

As for the differences between Browsers, `Chrome` [**does support lookbehinds**](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/07/upcoming-regexp-features%20fore%20further%20details).

Comment: chrome supports lookbehids.. i'll bet he only tested in chrome

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce.: I did post the link to the developer site quoting that they support lookbehinds. Nice nick name btw. :)