# [[:>:]] or [[:<:]] don't match

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use `[[:>:]]` in my regex but they are not accepted while other character classes e.g. `[[:digit:]]` or `[[:word:]]` are. What's going wrong?

[Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/z1n7nu/1)

Comment: Because it's not a character class. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Since those boundary assertions are not supported in PCRE?

Comment: if you see in example of regex101 ,use this and work but when I use not work , I test and learn all token of regex but this not work

Comment: These are word boundaries that are supported by most POSIX-like engines, see [this PostgreSQL regex demo](http://rextester.com/LRY59399). Regex101 does not support a regex flavor that supports these `[[:<:]]` / `[[:>:]]` word boundaries, use `\b` instead (supported by all 4: PCRE, JS, Python and Go).

Comment: might be good to provide the source of where it works and what context you're trying to use it in.

Comment: are you attempting to just serach for the < or > characters?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks

Comment: @happymacarts no , with `[[:<:]]` can get first characters of words

Comment: @revo: Shamkhal is right. They are supported by PCRE, but not by regex101. Search `COMPATIBILITY FEATURE FOR WORD BOUNDARIES` in http://pcre.org/original/pcre.txt

Comment: Frankly, I never noticed that, very good you pointed me to it. @CasimiretHippolyte

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I did not want a solution ,I wanted to know why it does not work, So I am looking for a reason not to work if you can bring a reason instead of a solution,Thank You

Comment: @MJNBelief That is entirely the initiative of the regex101.com team, I have no idea why they decided not to support the construct.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So this is a reason, please complete and answer

Comment: Ok, I re-added the answer with a bolded explanation. This is clearly a bug.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Great, Thanks

Comment: @MJNBelief I see you rely too much on regex101.com to learn regex. You should be very cautious when using it, as the author did not much care about the replacement patterns, and Python re implementation (Python flavor is actually PCRE with some deactivated features). The best way to learn is to combine regex101 + the real target environment, where you may combine the regex API with the patterns you test at regex101). There are other "caveats" as you have found out yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug, because these constructs (starting word boundary, `[[:<:]]`, and ending `[[:>:]]` word boundary) [are supported by the PCRE library itself](http://pcre.org/original/pcre.txt):

> ```
> COMPATIBILITY FEATURE FOR WORD BOUNDARIES
>
>   In  the POSIX.2 compliant library that was included in 4.4BSD Unix, the
>   ugly syntax [[:<:]] and [[:>:]] is used for matching  "start  of  word"
>   and "end of word". PCRE treats these items as follows:
>
>     [[:<:]]  is converted to  \b(?=\w)
>     [[:>:]]  is converted to  \b(?<=\w)
>
>   Only these exact character sequences are recognized. A sequence such as
>   [a[:<:]b] provokes error for an unrecognized  POSIX  class  name.  This
>   support  is not compatible with Perl. It is provided to help migrations
>   from other environments, and is best not used in any new patterns. Note
>   that  \b matches at the start and the end of a word (see "Simple asser-
>   tions" above), and in a Perl-style pattern the preceding  or  following
>   character  normally  shows  which  is  wanted, without the need for the
>   assertions that are used above in order to give exactly the  POSIX  be-
>   haviour.
> ```

When used in PHP code, it works:

```
if (preg_match_all('/[[:<:]]home[[:>:]]/', 'homeless and home', $m))
{
    print_r($m[0]); 
}
```

finds `Array ( [0] => home)`. See the [online PHP demo](https://ideone.com/dFzPZb).

**So, it is the regex101.com developer team that decided (or forgot) to include support for these paired word boundaries**.

**At regex101.com**, instead, use `\b` word boundaries (both as starting and ending ones) that are supported by all 4 regex101.com regex engines: PCRE, JS, Python and Go.

These word boundaries are mostly supported by POSIX-like engines, see this [PostgreSQL regex demo](http://rextester.com/LRY59399), for example. The `[[:<:]]HR[[:>:]]` regex finds a match in `Head of HR`, but finds no match in `<A HREF="some.html` and `CHROME`.

Other regex engines that support `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` word boundaries are base R (`gsub` with no `perl=TRUE` argument, e.g.) and MySQL.

In Tcl regex, there is `\m` for `[[:<:]]` (starting word boundary) and `\M` for ending word boundary (`[[:>:]]`).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `\b(?<=d)` or `\b(?=d)` instead. In any case PCRE engine converts `[[:<:]]` to `\b(?=\w)` and `[[:>:]]` to `\b(?<=\w)` before starting the match.

Comment: it's right , but  I am looking for a reason not to work ,I did not want a solution