# Add a character to the start of every word

Tags: r, regex

I have a vector of strings and want to add a + before each word in each string.

```
strings <- c('string one', 'string two', 'string three')
strings_new <- str_replace_all(strings, "\\b\\w", '+')
string_new
```

Unfortunately, this is replacing the first character, not adding the + symbol. I'm not too familiar with regex to know how to solve this.

Any help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: "(\b\w+)","+\\1"

Comment: Any packages that you are using should be included in the tags or in the body or your question. `str_replace_all` is not a base R function.

Comment: I wonder if `"\\<"` would work in default [extended regex](http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/base/html/regex.html) for matching word boundary at beginning or even posix `[[:<:]]`( probably not).

Comment: @bobblebubble That is what I tried in the first place, but it turns out there is the same bug as in Notepad++: `\\<` will add `+` before each word char, `[1] "+s+t+r+i+n+g +o+n+e"     "+s+t+r+i+n+g +t+w+o"    "+s+t+r+i+n+g +t+h+r+e+e"`. But `gsub("[[:<:]]", "+", strings, perl=TRUE)` works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using captured groups is one way of doing this.  Group with parenthesis and recall with `\\1`.

```
strings_new <- str_replace_all(strings, "(\\b\\w)", '+\\1')
strings_new
[1] "+string +one"   "+string +two"   "+string +three"
```

Comment: strings <- c('string one', 'string two', 'string three')
string_new <- paste("+", strings, sep = "")
string_new

Comment: related question: where do you go to look up the complete syntax for R's regex? I remember looking for it and being not very successful, so any hints appreciated

Comment: This is the link I use:
https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf

Comment: @DTYK That adds a `+` at the beginning of the string, not at the beginning of every word.

Answer (score 4):

You may use a **base R** solution using PCRE regex `[[:<:]]` that matches the *starting word boundary*, a location between a non-word and a word char:

```
strings <- c('string one', 'string two', 'string three')
gsub("[[:<:]]", "+", strings, perl=TRUE)
# => [1] "+string +one"   "+string +two"   "+string +three"
```

Or, you may use a `(\w+)` (that matches and captures into Group 1 any one or more word chars, i.e. letters, digits, or `_`) TRE regex to replace with a `+` and a replacement backreference `\1` to restore the consumed chars in the output:

```
gsub("(\\w+)", '+\\1', strings)
# => [1] "+string +one"   "+string +two"   "+string +three"
```

Note you do not need a word boundary here since the first word char matched will be already at the word boundary and the consequent word chars will be consumed due to `+` quantifier. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dRdsAp/1).

And with an ICU regex based `str_replace_all`, you may use

```
> str_replace_all(strings, "\\w+", '+\\0')
[1] "+string +one"   "+string +two"   "+string +three"
```

The `\\0` is  a replacement backreference to the whole match.

Comment: Note I cannot supply a regex101 demo for `gsub("[[:<:]]", "+", strings, perl=TRUE)` because of a [regex101 bug: it does not support `[[:<:]]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48742427/3832970)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without capture groups as well (as others have shown) by using the regex `\b(?=\w)` with `perl=T` as shown below.

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7ikKDMvvVjBRlchWUMdwlPIz0tV11GA8UrK85F5GUWpqeqaXOnFpUkaSjExSRr2tjEx5ZpKOgpK2kACaqCOQkFqUY5tiOb//wA)

```
strings <- c('string one', 'string two', 'string three')
gsub("\\b(?=\\w)", "+", strings, perl=T)
```

Result

```
[1] "+string +one"   "+string +two"   "+string +three"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative would be to use `strsplit()` in combination with `paste0()`:

```
res <- lapply(strsplit(strings, " "), function(x) paste0("+", x))
sapply(res, paste0, collapse = " ")
# [1] "+string +one"   "+string +two"   "+string +three"
```

For some people the advantage may be that you don't have to wrestle with a regular expression. However, I would always prefer the direct regex statements by Jasbner and Wictor