# Add a character to each word within a sentence in R

Tags: r, string, replace

I have sentences in R (they represent column names of an SQL query), like the following:

```
sample_sentence <- "CITY, AGE,NAME,LAST_NAME, COUNTRY"
```

I would need to add a character(s) like "k." in front of every word of the sentence. Notice how sometimes words within the sentence may be separated by a comma and a space, but sometimes just by a comma.
The desired output would be:

```
new_sentence <- "k.CITY, k.AGE,k.NAME,k.LAST_NAME, k.COUNTRY"
```

I would prefer to achieve this without using a loop for. I saw this post [Add a character to the start of every word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49405690/add-a-character-to-the-start-of-every-word) but there they work with a vector and I can't figure out how to apply that code to my example.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sample_sentence <- "CITY, AGE,NAME,LAST_NAME, COUNTRY"
gsub(pattern = "(\\w+)", replacement = "k.\\1", sample_sentence)
# [1] "k.CITY, k.AGE,k.NAME,k.LAST_NAME, k.COUNTRY"
```

Explanation: in regex `\\w+` matches one or more "word" characters, and putting it in `()` makes each match a "capturing group". We replace each capture group with `k.\\1` where `\\1` refers to every group captured by the first set of `()`.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution:

```r
sample_sentence <- "CITY, AGE,NAME,LAST_NAME, COUNTRY"

paste0("k.", gsub("(,\\s*)", "\\1k\\.", sample_sentence))

#> [1] "k.CITY, k.AGE,k.NAME,k.LAST_NAME, k.COUNTRY"
```