# RegEx C# doesnt Match when regex101 does

Tags: c#, regex, string, match

this is my pattern:

```
-{8}\s+((?:[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2})\s+(?:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}))\s+(?:LINE)\s+=\s+([0-9]{0,9})\s+(?:STN)\s+=\s+([0-9]{0,9})[ ]*(?:\n[ \S]*)*INCOMING CALL(?:[\S\s][^-])*
```

and this is my string:

```
--------   02/16/18   13:50:39   LINE = 0248   STN = 629     
       CALLING NUMBER   252
       NAME             Mar Ant
       UNKNOWN
       DNIS NUMBER      255
       BC = SPEECH
       VOIP CALL
00:00:00   INCOMING CALL    RINGING 0:09
       LINE = 0004
00:00:25   CALL RELEASED
```

it does match with several online regex testers but not with C# testers like http://regexstorm.net/tester, since

> .NET does not use Posix syntax

i notices that if i remove the last part of the pattern

```
INCOMING CALL(?:[\S\s][^-])*
```

it does match but still incorrect or at least not what i expect from it.

what should i change to make this pattern match the string ?

Comment: I had a new line (\n) in the end of my string that I obviously couldn't see. Solved it by trimming the input before validating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not related to the pattern type, the pattern is not actually POSIX compliant as regex escapes cannot be used inside bracket expressions (see `[\S\s]` in your pattern, which can be written as `.` together with `RegexOptions.Singleline` option, or as `(?s:.)`).

All you need to do here is to replace `\n` with `\r?\n` or `(?:\r\n?|\n)` to match Windows line break style.

Use

```
-{8}\s+((?:[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2})\s+(?:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}))\s+(?:LINE)\s+=\s+([0-9]{0,9})\s+(?:STN)\s+=\s+([0-9]{0,9})[ ]*(?:\r?\n[ \S]*)*INCOMING CALL(?:[\S\s][^-])*
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=-%7B8%7D%5Cs%2B%28%28%3F%3A%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%5C%2F%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%5C%2F%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%29%5Cs%2B%28%3F%3A%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%3A%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%3A%5B0-9%5D%7B2%7D%29%29%5Cs%2B%28%3F%3ALINE%29%5Cs%2B%3D%5Cs%2B%28%5B0-9%5D%7B0%2C9%7D%29%5Cs%2B%28%3F%3ASTN%29%5Cs%2B%3D%5Cs%2B%28%5B0-9%5D%7B0%2C9%7D%29%5B%20%5D*%28%3F%3A%5Cr%3F%5Cn%5B%20%5CS%5D*%29*INCOMING%20CALL%28%3F%3A%5B%5CS%5Cs%5D%5B%5E-%5D%29*&i=--------%20%20%2002%2F16%2F18%20%20%2013%3A50%3A39%20%20%20LINE%20%3D%200248%20%20%20STN%20%3D%20629%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20CALLING%20NUMBER%20%20%20252%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20NAME%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Mar%20Ant%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20UNKNOWN%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20DNIS%20NUMBER%20%20%20%20%20%20255%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20BC%20%3D%20SPEECH%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20VOIP%20CALL%0D%0A00%3A00%3A00%20%20%20INCOMING%20CALL%20%20%20%20RINGING%200%3A09%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20LINE%20%3D%200004%0D%0A00%3A00%3A25%20%20%20CALL%20RELEASED).