# Firebase Rules Regex Birthday

Tags: regex, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I am trying to validate birthdays using the following regex:

```
^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

This regex works when tested in an online regex tester, but when I try to use this regex inside my firebase rules, Firebase seems to not accept it. I also tried doubling my backslashes and still no luck.

This is my firebase rule:

```
".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().matches(/^(?:(?:31(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29(\/|-|\.)0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$/)"
```

This is the error I get on Firebase: "Illegal regular expression, unescaped ^, ^ can only appear at the end of regular expressions"

How can I tweak this regex to get it working on Firebase?

Comment: I tried doubling the backslashes and still no luck.

Comment: I'm still getting the exact same error :(

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to remove one `^`. See https://regex101.com/r/3pJKH8/2. The point is that you cannot repeat `^` and `$` inside the pattern, `^` and `$` are only allowed once at the beginning (`^`) and at the end (`$`)

Comment: This expression gets accepted by firebase with no errors, but when I try to pass in a birthday, the regex rejects it.

Comment: It should work, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/3pJKH8/3). Do you pass it as a string?

Comment: Yeah I do pass it as a string. Is it possible that Firebase has trouble reading expressions that have a "?:" inside of it? The reason I bring this up, is that originally my username regex validation had a ?: inside of it, which was causing the exact same problem (always reject the string). I had to use another expression that didn't have ?: in order to fix that problem.

Comment: That is what I have been checking now at https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/regex. Looks like no non-capturing groups are allowed in Firebase regex. So, replace `(?:` with `(`. It will require the backreference re-adjusting.

Comment: Does this require me adding a ? at the end of the bracket? Can you show me how it should look like?

Comment: See [this regex version #4](https://regex101.com/r/3pJKH8/4).

Comment: I tried v4 and it still rejects the birthday I pass in. This is what I try to pass in: "01/04/1998"

Comment: Try replacing `\\15` with `[-\\/.]`, does it work then? If not, use [this one](https://regex101.com/r/3pJKH8/5) since it means backreferences are not supported either. It will also match `04/04-1989` though, as it is not possible to match the same delimiter (well, it is possible, but you will have to write a much longer regex).

Comment: Thanks so much, replacing the //15 did the trick! Please update your answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things here:

- make sure all backslashes are doubled
- turn all non-capturing groups into capturing ones and re-adjust the backreferences (note that redundant capturing groups should be eliminated) (note you can't use `\15` as backreference, it seems only 1 to 9 backreferences are supported)
- re-vamp the pattern so that the `^` start of string anchor appeared at the beginning and `$` only at the end of the regular expression (otherwise, you will get the illegal regex exception). It is easy to do here as your pattern is of the `^a1$|^a2$|^a3$` type, and it is equal to `^(?:a1|a2|a3)$`.

The pattern should look like

```
newData.val().matches(/^((31([-\\/.])(0?[13578]|1[02])\\3|(29|30)([-\\/.])(0?[13-9]|1[0-2])\\6)(1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?\\d{2}|29([-\\/.])0?2\\9((1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)|(0?[1-9]|1\\d|2[0-8])([-\\/.])(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])[-\\/.](1[6-9]|[2-9]\\d)?\\d{2})$/)
```

Note that I also turned `(\/|-|\.)` into `([-\/.])` (since a character class is more efficient than plain alternation with single-char alternatives) and remove a comma from `[1,3-9]` - it looks like a typo, you wanted to match `1` or a digit from `3` to `9`, I believe, and a `,` is treated literally in a character class.

Comment: @RyanDailey I updated with a bit more precise version since you probably do not want to match `14/02-1954`, only `14/02/1954` or `14-02-1954`.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I tried using the updated regex and it is giving me an error, same error as I was getting before.

Comment: @RyanDailey  I have only split one alternative into 3. It is the only way to make your original regex work as required.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work without getting any errors in my Firebase console? As of now, the new regex answer you have submitted does not work.

Comment: @RyanDailey Ok, I rolled back to the previous version. I have no access to a Firebase console, so I cannot enhance it more. Still, [this more precise pattern](https://regex101.com/r/3pJKH8/8) looks correct taking into account all the restrictions we have come across.