# Regex max string length between commas but ignores whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to set the max string length between commas to 4.

I am using `^([^,?]{0,4},)*[^,?]{0,4}$`, which works fine. However if the user adds a space before the word, the current code counts that whitespace.

Example: 'this','will','be','fine'. <-- this works.

'this','   will','not','work' <-- this does Not work. Notice the whitespace before the ' will'. How do I modify my regex to not count this whitespace?

Comment: Do you want to match non-whitespace only comma/question mark separated entities? `^[^\s,?]{0,4}(?:,\s*[^\s,?]{0,4})*$`?

Comment: I tried your code but it does not work unfortunately. I just want to ignore the space before a word and not count it toward the max length. So 'will' = 4 chars. But ' will' = 5 chars. I want ' will' to be considered 4 chars since it should ignore the space. Note that the words are separated by commas..

Comment: Why didn't it work? What did you test it against? I assumed the words do not have whitespaces. Do you mean you also want to allow leading/trailing whitespace? Like `^\s*[^\s,?]{0,4}(?:\s*,\s*[^\s,?]{0,4})*\s*$`?

Comment: I added 'Hi, hows' to my form. It failed because it is counting hows as 5 chars instead of 4.

Comment: With [my regex](https://regex101.com/r/9WkAR5/1), it matches. With [your regex](https://regex101.com/r/9WkAR5/2), it does not match. So, if my regex does not work, does it mean your regex is fine?

Comment: Yours works fine in the regex101 test env, but when i use it in my formcontrol Validators.pattern, it doesnt work for some reason. Hmmm..

Comment: That means you are not using *my* pattern. It looks like `'\\s*[^\\s,?]{0,4}(?:\\s*,\\s*[^\\s,?]{0,4})*\\s*'` or `/^\s*[^\s,?]{0,4}(?:\s*,\s*[^\s,?]{0,4})*\s*$/` in the code. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/56098660/3832970

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
Validators.pattern('\\s*[^\\s,?]{0,4}(?:\\s*,\\s*[^\\s,?]{0,4})*\\s*')
Validators.pattern(/^\s*[^\s,?]{0,4}(?:\s*,\s*[^\s,?]{0,4})*\s*$/)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9WkAR5/1). Adjust the pattern by removing `\s*` anywhere you see fit.

Whenever you see a regex matches in the regex101.com tester and does not work in your code, always check the *Code generator* page link. See the [Regex not working in Angular Validators.pattern() while working in online regex testers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56098660/3832970) and [Regular expression works on regex101.com, but not on prod](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39636124/3832970).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespacs
- `[^\s,?]{0,4}` - zero to four chars other than whitespace, comma and a question mark
- `(?:\s*,\s*[^\s,?]{0,4})*` - zero or more sequences of a comma enclosed with zero or more whitespaces followed with zero to four chars other than whitespace, comma and a question mark
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `$` - end of string