# Regex returns no match in Dart but works in online regex testers

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I have built a regex which should match valid HTTP headers. It works, sort of, on regexr: https://regexr.com/4pnk9, with regex `^([\w\-])+:(?!\s*$).+$`. I am using the global, multi line and case insensitive flags (gim).

However when I implement it in my Flutter project, it does not match anything. Besides that Dart does not provide a way to enable global in RegExp.

Can anyone explain me why this regex works on regexr.com, but not in my Dart tests?

```
class Validators {
  static final RegExp _headerFieldsRegExp = RegExp(
      "^([\w\-])+:(?!\s*\$).+\$",
      multiLine: true,
      caseSensitive: false);

  static bool headerFieldsValid(String headerFields) {
    if (headerFields == null || headerFields.length == 0) {
      return false;
    }
    String match = _headerFieldsRegExp.stringMatch(headerFields);
    if (match == null) {
      return false;
    }
    return headerFields.length == match.length;
  }
}
```

```
void main() {
  test('Test validating header fields', () {
    String valid1 = 'Accept: json\nAuthorization: Bearer 12345';
    expect(true, Validators.headerFieldsValid(valid1));

    String valid2 = 'Accept: json\nAuthorization: Bearer 12345\n';
    expect(true, Validators.headerFieldsValid(valid2));

    String invalid1 = 'Accept: json\nAuthorization:\n';
    expect(false, Validators.headerFieldsValid(invalid1));

    String invalid2 = 'Accept: json\n\nAuthorization: Bearer 12345\n';
    expect(false, Validators.headerFieldsValid(invalid2));
  });
}
```

Comment: It should be `r"^([\w-])+:(?!\s*$).+$"` or `"^([\\w-])+:(?!\\s*\$).+\$"`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you totally missed that one. It works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may either use

```
r"^([\w-])+:(?!\s*$).+$"
```

or

```
"^([\\w-])+:(?!\\s*\$).+\$"
```

Note that inside a non-raw string literal, the double backslashes stand for a single literal backslash. In a raw string literal, you do not need to escape the `$` symbol and you only need a single backslash to form a regex escape.