# Getting Everything Between Two Characters Across New Lines

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

This is a sample of the text I am working with.

> 6) Jake's Taxi Service is a new entrant to the taxi industry. It has achieved success by staking out a unique position in the industry. How did Jake's Taxi Service mostly likely achieve this position?
>
> A) providing long-distance cab fares at a higher rate than
>   competitors; servicing a larger area than competitors
>
> B) providing long-distance cab fares at a lower rate than competitors;
>   servicing a smaller area than competitors
>
> C) providing long-distance cab fares at a higher rate than
>   competitors; servicing the same area as competitors
>
> D) providing long-distance cab fares at a lower rate than competitors;
>   servicing the same area as competitors
>
> Answer:  D

**I am trying to match the entire question including the answer options. Everything from the question number to the word Answer**

This is my current regex expression

```
((rf'(?<={searchCounter}\) ).*?(?=Answer).*'), re.DOTALL)
```

SearchCounter is just a variable that will correspond to the current question, in this case 6. I think the issue is something to do with searching across the new lines.

EDIT: Full source code

```
searchCounter = 1

bookDict = {}

with open ('StratMasterKey.txt', 'rt') as myfile:

    for line in myfile:
        question_pattern = re.compile((rf'(?<={searchCounter}\) ).*?(?=Answer).*'), re.DOTALL) 

        result = question_pattern.search(line)
        if result != None: 
            bookDict[searchCounter] = result[0] 
            searchCounter +=1
```

Comment: You actually get all text from the question number to the last `D`, see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qkBImf/2). How are you reading the file? `for line in file`? You need to read the file into a variable, like `contents = file.read()`.

Comment: I'm actually getting an empty dictionary when I run it in my project. Would you mind elaborating a little? I added my code.

Comment: When I try '(?<={searchCounter}\) ).*?(?=a)')' I get 'A good str' which seems to be working fine. It's only an issue when I try to span over the new line to the word Answer. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: It is a logic problem: you have `for line in myfile:`, you read line by line, but your pattern is written to find matches in a  single multiline string. Remove `for line in myfile:` and replace it with `contents = myfile.read()` then use `result = question_pattern.search(contents)`

Comment: Great! However, my only question is how do I iterate through the instances if I am not searching line by line?

Comment: `re.findall(rf'^{searchCounter}\)\s*([\s\S]*?)\nAnswer:\s*(.*)', contents, re.M)`?

Comment: Or, just them all, `re.findall(r'^(\d+)\)\s*([\s\S]*?)\nAnswer:\s*(.*)', contents, re.M)`

Comment: So what output do you need to get?

Comment: It's looking a lot better now. My end goal is to get the the whole question as well as the whole answer instead of just D, i.e. _D) providing long-distance cab fares at a lower rate than competitors; servicing the same area as competitors_ into a dictionary or list so that I can convert them into a csv. I have a file with over 1,000 questions.

Comment: So what are the specs? "A lot better" is the maximum I can do with your example. I hope you are not going to post all 1000 examples here.

Comment: You solved my question regarding the multiline issue. You asked what output do I need to get which I guess is out of the scope of this question :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212374/discussion-between-clayton-horning-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your regex fails is that you read the file *line by line* with `for line in myfile:`, while your pattern searches for matches in a *single multiline string*.

Replace `for line in myfile:` with `contents = myfile.read()` and then use `result = question_pattern.search(contents)` to get the first match, or `result = question_pattern.findall(contents)` to get multiple matches.

A note on the regex: I am not fixing the whole pattern since, as you mentioned, it is out of scope of this question, but since the string input is a multiline string now, you need to remove `re.DOTALL` and use `[\s\S]` to match any char in the pattern and `.` to match any char but a line break char. Also, the lookaround contruct is redundant, you may safely replace `(?=Answer)` with `Answer`. Also, to check if there is a match, you may simply use `if result:` and then grab the whole match value by accessing `result.group()`.

Full code snippet:

```
with open ('StratMasterKey.txt', 'rt') as myfile:
    contents = myfile.read()
    question_pattern = re.compile((rf'(?<={searchCounter}\) )[\s\S]*?Answer.*')) 
    result = question_pattern.search(contents)
    if result: 
        print( result.group() )
```