# How to use Regex to replace square brackets from date field in Google Data Studio?

Tags: regex, looker-studio, regexp-replace, re2

I am trying to remove square brackets around a date field in Google Data Studio so I can properly treat it as a proper date dimension.

It looks like this:

```
[2020-05-20 00:00:23]
```

and I am using the RegEx of `REGEXP_REPLACE(Date, "/[\[\]']+/g", "")` and I want it to look like this for the output:

```
2020-05-20 00:00:23
```

It keeps giving me error results and will not work. I can not figure out what I am doing wrong here, I've used https://www.regextester.com/ to verify that it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding Dates, it can be achieved with a single [TODATE](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7037300) [Calculated Field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685):

```
TODATE(Date, "[%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S]", "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
```

The Date Type can then be set as required:

- ***YYYYMMDD***: Date
- ***YYYYMMDDhh***: Date Hour
- ***YYYYMMDDhhmm***: Date Hour Minute

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/374faec5-a9f1-4455-82ee-15e4e15c99fd) and GIF to elaborate:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a plain regex pattern, not a regex literal notation (`/.../g`).

Note that [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7067058?hl=en) removes all occurrences found, thus, there is no need for a `g` flag.

Use

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(Date, "[][]+", "")
```

to remove all square brackets in `Date`.