# Regex to exclude list of domain in an email field not working

Tags: regex, modx

I'm trying to block certain domains from being accepted as an email.

I have looked online and found many answers but I cannot make them to work on my website

My current syntax is:

```
^(.+@)(?!domain_a|domain_b\.com)([A-Za-z0-9]+\.com)$
```

It works on a regex checker but fails on the site itself.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636124/regular-expression-works-on-regex101-com-but-not-on-prod. If that does not help, add the code to the question.

Comment: Only accepting email addresses in the `.com` top-level domain is obviously infuriating for anyone in `.edu` or a country TLD. Many email providers use ccTLDs like `.io` and `.cc` just for coolness. Please don't proliferate this horrible antipattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, maybe it is specific to the CMS, but the requirement was to add:

```
regexp=^/(.+@)(?!domain_a|domain_b.com)([A-Za-z0-9]+.com)$/^
```

Comment: What CMS? Where are you using the regex?

Comment: modx cms. I'm using it as a hook to filter emails using formit extra

Comment: So, https://forums.modx.com/thread/90219/how-to-use-regx-in-formit solves the issue