# JQuery Validate plugin - password check - underscore as single special character

Tags: jquery, regex, passwords

i try to validate PW with this code

```
$.validator.addMethod("pwcheck", function(value) {
return /[^\W\s]/gi.test(value) // match any wordCharacter
    && /[a-z]/.test(value) // has a lowercase letter
    && /[A-Z]/.test(value) // has a uppercase letter
    && /\d/.test(value) // has a digit      
    && /(?=.*?\W)/.test(value) // has a specialChar
});
```

Unfortunately it doesn´t work if my PW has a underscore as sinlge special chararcter, e.g. `1_Testing`

What can be done? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Replace `/(?=.*?\W)/` with `/(?=.*?[\W_])/`

Comment: This exactly answers your question. [Validation for passwords with special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62400363/validation-for-passwords-with-special-characters)

Comment: @Mandy8055 The questions are asked in a similar way, but the requirements and problem are different.

Comment: @Mandy8055 I might have misunderstood the question. Let's hear from OP, if summsel agrees with the duplicate, then I have misinterpreted the current problem.

Comment: No @WiktorStribiżew; I don't have any problem with the answer that you have. It's impeccable as always but I thought that it's a duplicate so thought to get your view on it.

Comment: @Mandy8055 your similar question is good, too.
Wiktors answer is straight to the point. Thx to both of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues that need a fix:

- `\W` also matches whitespaces, `[\W\s]` is equalt to `\W`. Thus, `/[^\W\s]/` should be just `/\w/`
- `\W` does not match underscores. When you require a special character and an underscore is treated as a special character, you need to use a `[\W_]` character class

Note also, that regexps used with `RegExp#test` should never be used with a `g` flag, it might lead to issues [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800) (not the case here, but as a best practice). Also, `\w` matches any lower- and uppercase ASCII letters, so not need to use a case insensitive `i` modifier here.

So, you may use

```
return /\w/.test(value)        // match any wordCharacter
    && /[a-z]/.test(value)     // has a lowercase letter
    && /[A-Z]/.test(value)     // has a uppercase letter
    && /\d/.test(value)        // has a digit      
    && /^[^\W_]*[\W_]/.test(value) // has a specialChar
});
```

The `^[^\W_]*[\W_]` pattern means

- `^` - match start of string
- `[^\W_]*` - 0 or more chars other than non-word chars or `_` (i.e. 0 or more letters or digits)
- `[\W_]` - a non-word char or a `_` char.