# Id match in firestore database rules

Tags: regex, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on my security rules, but when I try to match the document id with a regex, it doesn't work.
I tried to use the `matches` function, but it doesn't seem to accept the method.

Even when I tried using the Firebase pattern YYYY-MM-DD (`/^(19|20)[0-9][0-9][-\\/. ](0[1-9]|1[012])[-\\/. ](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$/`) from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/regex#usage), but it didn't work (I tried with 1950-01-01).

[image]

I am trying to check `roomId` for this pattern (`/^(\\d){6,}#[a-zA-Z0-9]{65,}$/`)

Edit: I tried removing the `" "` around the regex but it gives me this error: `mismatched input ')' expecting {'{', '/', PATH_SEGMENT}`

[image]

(I know the regex is OK, but I don't know why it won't work in the code I wrote)

Comment: Aparently the regex from Firebase works, please check [here](https://regex101.com/r/smmry6/1)

Comment: Remove `"` chars around the regex.

Comment: @marianc I know it works, but I can't make it work in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting the syntax mixed up between Realtime Database and Firestore.

In Realtime Database security rules, the regular expression is specific as a JavaScript regex, so enclosed in `/` for opening and closing.

In Firestore security rules the regular expression needs to be passed as a string, which also means it shouldn't be wrapped in `/` symbols.

So:

```
allow create: if docId.matches("^(19|20)[0-9][0-9][-\\/. ](0[1-9]|1[012])[-\\/. ](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$");
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the syntax was different.