# Extract url domain root in Google Sheet

Tags: regex, google-sheets, formula, google-sheets-formula

In a table, I have lists of full  urls like :

https://www.example.com/page-1/product-x?utm-source=google

Objective : I want to extract the domain name part of the url only :

https://www.example.com/

I was using this following formula :

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1;"^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:[^@\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?([^:\/\n?]+)")
```

The regex is working fine when [testing it](https://regex101.com/) :

```
https://www.example.com/
```

However in Google sheet, It displays like :

```
example.com
```

- Why the resutls are not the same for the identical regex ?
- How to correct it in google Sheet ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix the pattern by removing the capturing group (i.e. here, `([^:\/\n?]+)` => `[^:\/\n?]+`) or by converting the capturing groups to non-capturing ones (i.e. `([^:\/\n?]+)` => `(?:[^:\/\n?]+)`):

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1;"^(?:https?://)?(?:[^@\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?[^:/\n?]+")
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1;"^(?:https?://)?(?:[^@\n]+@)?(?:www\.)?(?:[^:/\n?]+)")
```

**NOTE**:

- If the regex contains capturing group(s), the `REGEXEXTRACT` returns captured value(s)
- If there are no capturing groups in the regex, the function returns the whole match value only.

Note you do not need to escape `/` forward slashes in RE2 regexps since they are defined with the help of string literals in Google Sheets.

The pattern may be reduced to `^(?:https?://)?[^:/\n?]+`, that matches `http://` or `https://` optionally, and then matches one or more chars other than `/`, newline, or `?`.

See [this RE2 regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FfWQOT/1).