# Find one or more word in string using Regex in Kotlin

Tags: regex, kotlin

I'm making a method in Kotlin using Regex that checks if a string contains one or more of certain pronouns (such as "I", "we", "you", etc). E.g. "We are a tech company" should be a match, "Web is for spiders" should not be a match.

I tried with this code:

```
fun main() {
    val text = "We are testing!"
    val regex = "/\b(i|you|we)\b/g".toRegex()
    if (regex.containsMatchIn(text.lowercase())) {
        println("match")
    } else {
        println("no match")
    }
}
```

, but it prints "no match".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kotlin (and Java) regexps are defined with string literals, and not regex literals, i.e. when you add `/` at the start and `/g` (or just `/`) at the end of the pattern, you actually add them to the *pattern string*.

You can use the following fix:

```kotlin
val text = "We are testing!"
val regex = """(?i)\b(i|you|we)\b""".toRegex()
if (regex.containsMatchIn(text)) {
    println("match")
} else {
    println("no match")
}
```

The `"""(?i)\b(i|you|we)\b"""` is equal to `"(?i)\\b(i|you|we)\\b"`, the former treats backslashes as literal chars.

Note you do not need to use `.lowercase()`, the `(?i)` case insensitive modifier will make matching case insensitive.

See the [online Kotlin demo](https://ideone.com/jDuCma).