# RegEx: lookahead get only first occurrence

Tags: javascript, regex

(modified) Trying to get only first match of condition `(?<=Location:.*?\().*?(?=\))`

Here is data:

```
--batchresponse_bla_bla_bla_\r\n--changesetresponse__bla_bla_bla_\r\nLocation: https://site.ru/CRM/api/data/v9.0/gm_preorders(a341eb4e-2fdf-eb11-a30b-ac1f6b465e3b)\r\nOData-EntityId: https://site.ru/CRM/api/data/v9.0/gm_preorders(a341eb4e-2fdf-eb11-a30b-ac1f6b465e3b)\r\n_bla_bla_bla_\r\n--changesetresponse__bla_bla_bla_Location: https://site.ru/CRM/api/data/v9.0/gm_preorders(a841eb4e-2fdf-eb11-a30b-ac1f6b465e3b)\r\nOData-EntityId: https://site.ru/CRM/api/data/v9.0/gm_preorders(a841eb4e-2fdf-eb11-a30b-ac1f6b465e3b)\r\n_bla_bla_bla_\r\n--changesetresponse_n_bla_bla_bla_\r\nLocation: https://site.ru/CRM/api/data/v9.0/gm_preorders(74748d08-2ee6-eb11-a30b-ac1f6b465e3b)\r\nOData-EntityId: https://site.ru/CRM/api/data/v9.0/gm_preorders(74748d08-2ee6-eb11-a30b-ac1f6b465e3b)\r\nn_bla_bla_bla_\r\n--changesetresponse_etc
```

and it returns:

```
match 1:    a341eb4e-2fdf-eb11-a30b-ac1f6b465e3b
match 2:    a341eb4e-2fdf-eb11-a30b-ac1f6b465e3b
match 3:    a841eb4e-2fdf-eb11-a30b-ac1f6b465e3b
match 4:    a841eb4e-2fdf-eb11-a30b-ac1f6b465e3b
match 5:    74748d08-2ee6-eb11-a30b-ac1f6b465e3b
match 6:    74748d08-2ee6-eb11-a30b-ac1f6b465e3b
```

Is there a possibility to match only first occurrence of each match (so i need 3 matches: 1, 3 and 5) with lookbehind and lookahead and without grouping or other conditions?

Found solution with a help:

```
(?<=Location:[^(]*?\().*?(?=\))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```js
(?<=Location:[^(]*\([^(]*\()[^)]*(?=\))
(?<=Location:[\w\W]*?\()(.*?)(?=\))(?![\w\W]*\1)
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/PlVnxP/5) and [regex #2 demo](https://regex101.com/r/PlVnxP/3).

*Details*:

- `(?<=Location:[^(]*\([^(]*\()` -  a location preceded with `Location:`, zero or more chars other than `(`, a `(`, and then again zero or more chars other than `(` and then a `(`
- `[^)]*` - zero or more chars other than `)`
- `(?=\))` - a `)` char must appear immediately on the right.
- `(?<=Location:[\w\W]*?\()` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with

  - `Location:` - a `Location:` string
  - `[\w\W]*?` - zero or more chars as few as possible
  - `\(` - a `(` char
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\))` - immediately to the right, there must be a `)` char.
- `(?![\w\W]*\1)` - no Group 1 value cannot be located further in the string.

Comment: hi, i've changed question cause it wasnt full enough. And my engine cant get "(?s:.)" expression.

Comment: @kmish My regex still works. Did you try it? What is your regex engine? If it supports `\A`, it supports `(?s:...)`. Please check the other solution I have just added.

Comment: first code doesnt work - https://regex101.com/r/JRij0x/1,
second one founds 6 matches as my original one

Comment: i need not only first but 1st, 3rd and 5th, etc. Like each time lookahead must stop after first `)`, but it captures both occurrences following before.

Comment: doesnt - https://regex101.com/r/TFT05l/1, do not change \r\n to new line. original is single line string

Comment: @kmish `\r\n` are line endings, CRLF. There are no `\r\n` in the plain text. Try the regex in your original environment. Do not use regex101 now. Read [My regex works at regex101.com, but not in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39636208/3832970). If you do not explain where and how you use the regex, you might never solve this problem.

Comment: @kmish Read [My regex works at regex101.com, but not in](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39636208/3832970).

Comment: anyway it doesnt work on original line as well as solution becomes to complex, easier to filter it afterward

Comment: @kmish Of course it is much easier to solve without a regex, or a combination of a simple regex + a bit of code. Where are you using the regex? Btw, also, see `(?<=Location:[^(]*\([^(]*\()[^)]*(?=\))` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/PlVnxP/5).. This is more a workaround but is probably sufficient in this case.

Comment: @kmish Added this workaround solution to the answer.

Comment: with your last example modifing my original `(?<=Location:.*?\().*?(?=\))` with `[^(]*?` is making `(?<=Location:[^(]*?\().*?(?=\))` and works like a charm, simple and fast. thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

You may use this dynamic length lookbehind assertion in a regex without using `MULTILINE` mode:

```sh
(?<=^(?:(?!\bLocation:)[^])*?\bLocation:[^(]*\()[^)]+
```

- [RegEx Demo - Javascript](https://regex101.com/r/anLGM8/3)
- [RegEx Demo - .Net](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%28%3f%3a%28%3f!%5cbLocation%3a%29%5b%5cs%5cS%5d%29*%3f%5cbLocation%3a%5b%5e%28%5d*%5c%28%29%5b%5e%29%5d%2b&i=--batchresponse_bla_bla_bla_%0d%0a--changesetresponse__bla_bla_bla_%0d%0a--%0d%0aLocation%3a+https%3a%2f%2fsite.ru%2fCRM%2fapi%2fdata%2fv9.0%2fgm_preorders%28a341eb4e-2fdf-eb11-a30b-ac1f6b465e3b%29%0d%0aOData-EntityId%3a+https%3a%2f%2fsite.ru%2fCRM%2fapi%2fdata%2fv9.0%2fgm_preorders%28a341eb4e-2fdf-eb11-a30b-ac1f6b465e3b%29%0d%0a_bla_bla_bla_%0d%0a--changesetresponse__bla_bla_bla_Location%3a+https%3a%2f%2fsite.ru%2fCRM%2fapi%2fdata%2fv9.0%2fgm_preorders%28a841eb4e-2fdf-eb11-a30b-ac1f6b465e3b%29%0d%0aOData-EntityId%3a+https%3a%2f%2fsite.ru%2fCRM%2fapi%2fdata%2fv9.0%2fgm_preorders%28a841eb4e-2fdf-eb11-a30b-ac1f6b465e3b%29%0d%0a_bla_bla_bla_%0d%0a--changesetresponse_n_bla_bla_bla_%0d%0aLocation%3a+https%3a%2f%2fsite.ru%2fCRM%2fapi%2fdata%2fv9.0%2fgm_preorders%2874748d08-2ee6-eb11-a30b-ac1f6b465e3b%29%0d%0aOData-EntityId%3a+https%3a%2f%2fsite.ru%2fCRM%2fapi%2fdata%2fv9.0%2fgm_preorders%2874748d08-2ee6-eb11-a30b-ac1f6b465e3b%29%0d%0an_bla_bla_bla_%0d%0a--changesetresponse_etc)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<=`: Start lookbehind condition

  - `^`: Start position
  - `(?:(?!\bLocation:)[\s\S])*?`: Match 0 or more of any character including newline as long as it is not followed by `Location:` word
  - `\bLocation:`: Match word `Location:`
  - `[^(]*\(`: Followed by 0 or more non-`(` characters and a `(`
- `)`: End lookbehind condition
- `[^)]+`: Match 1+ of any character that is not a `)`

Comment: hey, i've found that my question was not full. i've modified it. with new conditions this solution doesnt work

Comment: Check my updated answer and new demo links