# matching new line in Scala regex, when reading from file

Tags: regex, scala, newline, whitespace

For processing a file with SQL statements such as:

```
ALTER TABLE ONLY the_schema.the_big_table
    ADD CONSTRAINT the_schema_the_big_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (the_id);
```

I am using the regex:

```
 val primaryKeyConstraintNameCatchingRegex: Regex = "([a-z]|_)+\\.([a-z]|_)+\n\\s*(ADD CONSTRAINT)\\s*([a-z]|_)+\\s*PRIMARY KEY”.r
```

Now the problem is that this regex does not return any results, despite the fact that both the regex

```
val alterTableRegex = “ALTER TABLE ONLY\\s+([a-z]|_)+\\.([a-z]|_)+”.r
```

and

```
val addConstraintRegex = “ADD CONSTRAINT\\s*([a-z]|_)+\\s*PRIMARY KEY”.r
```

match the intended sequences.

I thought the problem could be with the new line, and, so far, I have tried writing `\\s+`, `\\W+`, `\\s*`, `\\W*`, `\\n*`, `\n*`, `\n+`, `\r+`, `\r*`, `\r\\s*`, `\n*\\s*`, `\\s*\n*\\s*`, and other combinations to match the white space between the table name and `add constraint` to no avail.

I would appreciate any help with this.

**Edit**

This is the code I am using:

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex
import java.io.File

import scala.io.Source


object Hello extends Greeting with App {

  val primaryKeyConstraintNameCatchingRegex: Regex = "([a-z]|_)+\\.([a-z]|_)+\r\\s*(ADD CONSTRAINT)\\s*([a-z]|_)+\\s*PRIMARY KEY".r


  readFile

  def readFile: Unit = {
    val fname = "dump.sql"
    val fSource = Source.fromFile(fname)


    for (line <- fSource.getLines) {
      val matchExp = primaryKeyConstraintNameCatchingRegex.findAllIn(line).foreach(
        segment => println(segment)
      )
    }

    fSource.close()


  }
}
```

**Edit 2**

Another strange behavior is that when matching with

```
"""[a-z_]+(\.[a-z_]+)\s*A""”.r
```

the matches happen and they include `A`, but when I use

```
"""[a-z_]+(\.[a-z_]+)\s*ADD""”.r
```

which is only different in `DD`, no sequence is matched.

Comment: Can you show the related code? What is the expected output? Matching whitespace is done with `\s`, so `\n\\s*` must be written as `\\s*`. Or, you can try using `\R` instead of `\n`, ``\\R\\s*`` if you need to make sure there is a line break.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the tips. I added the sample code. I just want to print the sequences matching the regex in a file. I get the desired output with the two alternative regex sections but not with the main one.

Comment: `"([a-z]|_)+\\.([a-z]|_)+\\R\\s*(ADD CONSTRAINT)\\s*([a-z]|_)+\\s*PRIMARY KEY”.r` didn’t work either.

Comment: See [this demo](https://rextester.com/NBQ55700). Your problem is that you read the file line by line (see `for (line <- fSource.getLines)`). You need to grab the contents as a single string to be able to match across line breaks.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am convinced this is a bug: `"([a-z]|_)+\\.([a-z]|_)+\\s+A”.r` does match, while `"([a-z]|_)+\\.([a-z]|_)+\\s+ADD”.r` does not. The difference is just adding the `DD`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you very much. Sorry. that was a very dumb mistake.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but what does explain the `DD` phenomenon?

Comment: Sorry, that is not possible. If `ADD` matches, `A` must match, too. This is common logic. You are using `findAllIn`, this searches for partial matches, thus it just can't do what you say. Either both match, or none.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I mean `A` matches, but `ADD` does not. Logically what you are stating is correct. that’s why I think this behavior can only be caused by a bug.

Comment: It might not be a bug. Your pattern is convoluted, `([a-z]|_)+` must be written as `[a-z_]+`. Try replacing them and check.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks. I checked with `"""[a-z_]+(\.[a-z_]+)\s*A""”.r` and `"""[a-z_]+(\.[a-z_]+)\s*ADD""".r` same thing with `readLine`. Yet, when I just call `.mkString` on the `fSource` and pass it to the `findAllIn`, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you read the file line by line (see `for (line <- fSource.getLines)` code part).

You need to grab the contents as a single string to be able to match across line breaks.

```
val fSource = Source.fromFile(fname).mkString
val matchExps = primaryKeyConstraintNameCatchingRegex.findAllIn(fSource)
```

Now, `fSource` will contain the whole text file contents as one string and `matchExps` will contain all found matches.