# Regex matching works on regex tester but not in oracle

Tags: regex, oracle, oracle10g

I have the regex `\bname[^a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+`. This regex works on https://regexr.com/ but does not work in oracle. The pattern I am going for is:
`<exact word "name" (upper or lower case)><any character/s that is a non-alphabet (including line breaks) or it can be no character><a whole number>`

Where is my testing sample:

```
name8213

name:1232

name: 234

name 
1231

name: 
985

name:, 123

-- Should not match any of the below text

nameis1233

name is 123

ornaments are cool 360

nickname 1323

name 1234 1233 (should not match the second set of numbers)
```

However, when I execute

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('name 123', '\bname[^a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+', 1, 1, 'i') FROM DUAL
```

I get nothing out. My end goal is to just extract that whole number.

Comment: You need to escape the backslash in the Oracle string.

Comment: @Barmar How would I do that? By adding another `\`?

Comment: Change `\b` to `\\b`.

Comment: @Barmar I tried that and I still get nothing back

Comment: The reason you don't get a match is that your string `'name 123'` does not match your pattern because it has an embedded blank after 'name'.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica If I put that into a regex tester website, it still matches `name 123`

Comment: Oracle regex does NOT support word boundaries.

Comment: How would I get around that @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: `SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('name 123', '(\W|^)(name[^a-zA-Z]*[0-9]+)', 1, 1, 'i', 2) FROM DUAL`, but `[^a-zA-Z]+`  looks out of place here. You really need `[^0-9]*`, else, `+` after `[0-9]` is redundant and you may overmatch. Ah, and it should be `*`, not `+`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That seems to work, but also seems to match `name 123 222`. It should not match `222` Any idea how I may stop that?

Comment: `(\W|^)(name\W*[0-9]+)`? Or `(\W|^)(name[^[:alnum:]]*[0-9]+)` if you allow underscore there.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Perfect. You can make that the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle regex does not support word boundaries.

In this case, you need to do three things:

- Use the `(\W|^)` as the leading word boundary construct substitute and
- Wrap the part of the regex you need to get as a return with another capturing group, and later get it using the right argument to the `REGEXP_SUBSTR` function
- Replace the `[^a-zA-Z]+` with `\W*` (or `[^[:alnum:]]*`  if you allow underscores there), as your intention is to match any non-word chars between `name` and a number, and fail all matches with letters and digits in between them.

You can use

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('name 123', '(\W|^)(name\W*[0-9]+)', 1, 1, 'i', 2) FROM DUAL
```

The last argument, `2`, tells the `REGEXP_SUBSTR` to fetch the value of the second capturing group.

*Details*:

- `(\W|^)` - Group 1: a non-word char (any char other than a letter, digit or underscore) or start of string
- `(name\W*[0-9]+)` - Group 2: `name`, then any zero or more non-word chars  (or any zero or more non-alphanumeric chars if you use `[^[:alnum:]]*`)and then one or more digits.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not support word boundaries `\b` in regular expressions:

```sql
SELECT value,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '(\W|^)(name[^a-zA-Z]*?\d+)', 1, 1, 'n', 2) AS match
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT 'name8213' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'name:1232' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'name: 234' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'name 
1231' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'name: 
985' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'name:, 123' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'nameis1233' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'name is 123' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'ornaments are cool 360' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'nickname 1323' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'name 1234 1233' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| VALUE | MATCH |
| --- | --- |
| name8213 | name8213 |
| name:1232 | name:1232 |
| name: 234 | name: 234 |
| name 1231 | name 1231 |
| name: 985 | name: 985 |
| name:, 123 | name:, 123 |
| nameis1233 |  |
| name is 123 |  |
| ornaments are cool 360 |  |
| nickname 1323 |  |
| name 1234 1233 | name 1234 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4b0ca23bb8ef94af64a24b997c1ea617)*