# Support for negative lookbehind regex in app.yaml

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, regex-lookarounds, app.yaml

I am trying to exclude all source map files, i.e files ending with `.map` from being uploaded to app engine.
Here's a snippet of the config in `app.yaml` file.

```
handlers:
- url: /(.*\\..+(?\<!map))$
  static_files: \\1
  upload: /(.*\\..+(?\<!map))$
  secure: always
```

However, when deploying, this is the error that I get.

```
content <{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "The request is invalid.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "version.handlers[0].url_regex",
            "description": "Value \"/(.*\\..+(?\\\u003c!map))$\" must be a valid regular expression. Details: invalid or unsupported Perl syntax."
          },
          {
            "field": "version.handlers[0].static_files.upload_path_regex",
            "description": "Value \"/(.*\\..+(?\\\u003c!map))$\" must be a valid regular expression. Details: invalid or unsupported Perl syntax."
          }
        ]
      }
```

In the `app.yaml` reference documentation, it implies that it supports [POSIX extended regular expression syntax](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#syntax).

Might anyone advice on what should be done to fix this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
^(.*([^.].{3}|.[^m].{2}|.{2}[^a].|.{3}[^p])|.{0,3})$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7LT5Fs/2). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*([^.].{3}|.[^m].{2}|.{2}[^a].|.{3}[^p])|.{0,3})` - Group 1 matching:

  - `.*([^.].{3}|.[^m].{2}|.{2}[^a].|.{3}[^p])` - any text, and then any of

    - `[^.].{3}|` - a char other than a `.` and then any 3 chars, or
    - `.[^m].{2}|` - any char, a char other than `m`, and then any two chars, or
    - `.{2}[^a].|` - any two chars, any char other than `a`, and then any one char
    - `.{3}[^p]` - any three chars, and then a char other than `p`
  - `|` - or
  - `.{0,3}` - any zero, one, two or three chars.
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Amazing. Many thanks. However, I've shortened it like so ```^(.*(.[^m].{2}|.{2}[^a].|.{3}[^p]))$``` . This seems to work too.

Comment: @Curtis Your `^(.*(.[^m].{2}|.{2}[^a].|.{3}[^p]))$` pattern won't find `a.a`, `.aa`, `.a`, `a` strings, that is probably fine in your case, but the pattern does not meet the "match any string not ending with `.map`" requirement set out in your question above.

Comment: I agree. And this is because I am tested this incorrectly. Many thanks for pointing it out. Useful links can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39636124/regular-expression-works-on-regex101-com-but-not-on-prod