# Regular expression: Match everything after a particular word until multiple occurence of carriage return and new line

Tags: python, regex

I am using Python and would like to match all the words after "Examination(s):" till one or more empty lines occur.

```
text = "Examination(s):\sMathematics 2nd Paper\r\n\r\nTimeTable"
text = "Examination(s):\r\n\r\nMathematics 2nd Paper\r\nblahblah"
text = "Examination(s):\r\nMathematics 2nd Paper\r\n\r\n\r\nmarks"
```

In all the above examples, my output should be "Mathematics 2nd Paper". Here is what I tried:

```
import re
pat = re.compile(r'(?:Examination\(s\):)[^\r\n]*')
re.search(pat,text)
```

The above snippet works fine for example 2 (one occurrence of \r\n), but is not working for examples 1 and 3.

I am getting this error when i tried to apply your pattern @Wiktor

[image]

Updating the question to capture the missed scenario, it can be a space or newline after colon

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: Works fine! take a look at https://regex101.com/r/GfAWMF/1

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani Your regex test is invalid, you are not testing against the literal text, but against a string literal.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Can you be more specific? By "literal text" do you mean a text file?

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani All you need to know is available at [Regular expression works on regex101.com, but not on prod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39636208/3832970), scroll to *All languages - "Literal string" vs. "String literal" alert* section.

Comment: Ok, so what about `re.search(r'Examination\(s\):\r?\n([^\r\n]+)', text)`? See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/bpYwTE).

Comment: I wonder if there is a reason for using `[^\r\n]+` instead of `.+`

Comment: @bobblebubble In Python `re`, `.` matches a CR char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the line after `Examination(s):` you can use

```py
re.search(r'Examination\(s\):\s*([^\r\n]+)', text)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ER3lzG/2). *Details*:

- `Examination\(s\):` - a literal `Examination(s):` string
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `([^\r\n]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than CR and LF chars.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/bpYwTE):

```py
import re
texts = ["Examination(s):\r\nMathematics 2nd Paper\r\n\r\nTimeTable",
    "Examination(s):\r\nMathematics 2nd Paper\r\nblahblah",
    "Examination(s):\r\nMathematics 2nd Paper\r\n\r\n\r\nmarks"]
 
for text in texts:
    m = re.search(r'Examination\(s\):\s*([^\r\n]+)', text)
    print(f'--- {repr(text)} ---')
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

Output:

```
--- 'Examination(s):\r\nMathematics 2nd Paper\r\n\r\nTimeTable' ---
Mathematics 2nd Paper
--- 'Examination(s):\r\nMathematics 2nd Paper\r\nblahblah' ---
Mathematics 2nd Paper
--- 'Examination(s):\r\nMathematics 2nd Paper\r\n\r\n\r\nmarks' ---
Mathematics 2nd Paper
```

Comment: I am getting an error, uploaded the screenshot of the error in my question. Thank you.

Comment: @dsj Because there is no match, in that string, you do not have a line break after `:` and all the strings in the question contain a line break there. Replace `\r?\n`, or `[\r\n]+`, with `(?:\r?\n)?`  or a more generic `\s*` then.

Comment: Apologies yes you are right, it worked now, but yes it will have space in some text, newline in some text, does \s* works for all that cases?

Comment: @dsj `\s*` matches zero or more whitespaces, all Unicode whitespaces.

Comment: Ah yes, it fails whenever there is newline character in there, how do I match both spaces and newlines here? Because some examples will have space, some will have one newline, some will have 2 new lines.

Comment: @dsj See a [Whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character) wiki article.

Comment: It works, thank you. updated the examples in the question to captured missed ones. Apologies, Thanks for pointing out.